# Where is the /var folder?

Tags: centos

I have new centos 6.6 install. When I do a df-h I get the following. My worry now should I resinstall to create a separate /var or leave it where it will be enough? Where will the /var be in the / or /home ?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_tt-lv_root
                      219G 1009M  207G   1% /
tmpfs                 7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             477M   47M  405M  11% /boot
/dev/sda1             200M  260K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg_tt-lv_home
                       48G   52M   46G   1% /home
```

Comment: Why do you believe you need a separate filesystem for `/var`?

Comment: I am going to run mysql so worried one day it might be big enough and normally I know the default var size is 50G will this effect here?  or in this case it will be 219G ?

Comment: @user4126382 Well, since `/var` isn't treated specially, it's just a directory under the `/` filesystem on your current setup, then yes. You can fit another 207 GB into `/var` before you'd have serious problems. It's not always necessary to have everything under different partitions.

Comment: @ParthianShot thank you. Why is the need for different partition does it makes any difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depends on space that you need. If you need a lot of space for /var so you can using lvm partition when you install OS at first time at partitioning system. When your partition using LVM so you can extend /var system if you need space more than before. I'm guess, you use default partitioning system so /var be a part of directory /.

Comment: Yes I think its the default partition but if I leave it now with the 219G 1009M  207G   1% / will it be ok for /var to grow right?

Comment: it's depends at your capacity server. when you using the default partition, you can't extend /var partition if someday you need a more space but if you using lvm, you can extend /var anytime you need it

Comment: When you say extend in future means ? when I have new hard disk is it ?